# Delete error in a file (c programming)

Tags: c, file

I have a program that its purpose is to create an employee file,  then from that file that has been created the user can delete a record, update it or retreive it, the problem that I'm having is that when the user enters 2 to delete a record and the record is deleted by the Delete Function ( which transfer all the record except 3 which is the id that I intent to delete) then the display function needs to display the updated file, but it keeps on giving this error "An error occurred opening the file" I believe that happens because the file gets delete after the delete function is executed,can someone please guide me or tell me what is wrong with my code

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define KEY_SIZE 100

typedef struct employee{
  int id;
  char name[40];
  float pay;
}EMP;

void CreateEmployee();
void DisplayRecord();
void DeleteRecord(int );
void menuEmployee();
void StoreTemp(struct employee data[],FILE *fp,int ,int );

int main() {
    menuEmployee();
    return 0;
}


 void menuEmployee(){
    int choice=0;
    printf("      Please select an Option\n");
    puts("");
    printf("\t1:Create Employee\n");
    printf("\t2:Delete Employee\n");
    printf("\t3:Update Employee\n");
    printf("\t4:Retrieve Employee\n");
    printf("\t5:Display Employee\n");
    puts("");
    printf("\t    6:Exit\n\t      ");
    scanf("%d",&choice);

     switch((choice-1)){
      case 0:
        CreateEmployee();
        break;
      case 1:
        DeleteRecord(3);
        DisplayRecord();
        break;
      case 2:
        //UpdateEmployee();
        break;
      case 3:
        //RetrieveEmployee();
        break;
      case 4:
        DisplayRecord();
        break;
      case 5:
        exit(0);
      default:
        printf("No such option Exist");
        break;
   }
 }


void DeleteRecord(int id){
   EMP test[KEY_SIZE];
   FILE *fp;
   FILE *tfp;
   int length;
   int i =0;
   fp=fopen("employee.txt","r");
   tfp=fopen("temp.txt","a");
   if(fp != NULL){
    length=ReadContents(test,fp,id);
    length=length-1;
   }
   StoreTemp(test,tfp,length,id);
   fclose(fp);
   remove("employee.txt");
   rename("temp.txt","employee.txt");

   fclose(tfp);
 }

int ReadContents(struct employee test[],FILE *fp,int id)
{

   int count=0;
   int i;
   while(!feof(fp)){
    fscanf(fp,"%i %s %f",&test[count].id,test[count].name,&test[count].pay);
    count++;
  }


  return count;
 }

void CreateEmployee(){
   char choice ='y';
   int i=0;
   long int pos;
   EMP x[20];


   FILE *fp;
   FILE *keyfp;
   fp = fopen("employee.txt","a");
   keyfp =fopen("Key.txt","a");
   if (fp==NULL){
     printf("File not created");
   }
   while((choice == 'Y') || (choice =='y')){
     printf("Enter the employee's id:");
     scanf("%i",&x[i].id);
     fprintf(fp,"%i\t",x[i].id);

     printf("\nEnter the employee's name:");
     scanf("%s",x[i].name);
     fprintf(fp,"%s\t",x[i].name);

     printf("\nEnter the employee's pay:");
     scanf("%f",&x[i].pay);
     fprintf(fp,"%.2f\t\n",x[i].pay);
     printf("\nEnter another employee?\n");
     printf("Y - Yes     N - No:\n");

     scanf("\n%c",&choice);
     i++;
  }

  fclose(fp);
  fclose(keyfp);
  menuEmployee();
}


void StoreTemp(struct employee data[],FILE *fp,int length,int id){
   int i=0;
   for(i=0;i<length;i++){
    if(data[i].id != id){
        fprintf(fp,"%i\t%s\t%.2f\n",data[i].id,data[i].name,data[i].pay);
      }

   }
 }


void DisplayRecord(){

   EMP temp;

   FILE *fp = fopen("employee.txt", "r");

   if(fp != NULL)
  {
     printf("ID\tNAME\tSALARY\n");
     while(1)
      {
         fscanf(fp, "%i %s  %f", &temp.id, temp.name, &temp.pay);
         if (feof(fp))
            break;
         printf("%i\t%s\t%.2f\n",temp.id, temp.name, temp.pay);

      }

       fclose(fp);
     }
     else
     {
       printf("An error occurred opening the file\n");
     }
  }
```

Comment: Have you tried closing temp.txt (`tfp` in `DeleteRecord()`) before renaming it?  Though since you read all the records into memory anyway, I don't see why you couldn't write the changes to the original file directly... Also, shouldn't you open `temp.txt` in write mode rather than append mode?

Comment: tried that already like monty said but now the error does not even come up

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to rename a file that is still open. Swap these two lines:

```
   rename("temp.txt","employee.txt");
   fclose(tfp);
```

To this:

```
   fclose(tfp);
   rename("temp.txt","employee.txt");
```

Comment: ok thanks just a question the remove("employee.txt"); will not be executed first and then what file is going to rename if it was eliminated?

Comment: well now the employee.txt is there but the display function just does not work at all

Comment: Again open the file after renaming it @JorgitoAqui